# I want to rewrite article using python script with an API from APLLayer

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code block from APILayer.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.apilayer.com/paraphraser"

payload = "{body}".encode("utf-8")
headers= {
  "apikey": "2PbDGE6E........"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

status_code = response.status_code
result = response.text
```

Now I want to use it to rewrite an article. Please help me to do that.

Documentation of this API: https://apilayer.com/marketplace/paraphraser-api

Comment: Hi, welcome. What have you tried so far? The response is valid JSON?